# identify zeros in list of list python itertools

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a look which looks like the following:

```
yyy=[(2.0, 3.4, 3.75), (2.0, 3.4, 0.0), (2.0, 3.4, 0.0), (2.0, 3.4, 3.5), (2.0, 3.4, 0.0)]
```

What I would like to do is identify if 0.0 is present in any of the sublists (true or false). So, I follow itertools, but I am unsure how the logic should be constructed.

```
from itertools import *
selectors = [x is 0 for x in yyy]
#[False, False, False, False, False]
```

Obviously, my above sytax does not seem right - I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction for the syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try  `[0.0 in x for x in yyy]`

```
>>> yyy=[(2.0, 3.4, 3.75), (2.0, 3.4, 0.0), (2.0, 3.4, 0.0), (2.0, 3.4, 3.5), (2.0, 3.4, 0.0)]
>>> [0.0 in x for x in yyy]
[False, True, True, False, True]
>>>
```

You were close.

Comment: Hi Eric: Thanks.. This looks neat

Comment: Should not matter. 0.0 is equal to 0 in Python 2.7 for me.

Answer (score 1):

what about just:

```
any(0.0 in subtup for subtup in yyy)
```

demo:

```
>>> yyy=[(2.0, 3.4, 3.75), (2.0, 3.4, 0.0), (2.0, 3.4, 0.0), (2.0, 3.4, 3.5), (2.0, 3.4, 0.0)]
>>> any(0.0 in subtup for subtup in yyy)
True
>>> yyy=[(2.0, 3.4, 3.75), (2.0, 3.4, 10.0), (2.0, 3.4, 10.0), (2.0, 3.4, 3.5), (2.0, 3.4,10.0)]
>>> any(0.0 in subtup for subtup in yyy)
False
```

Comment: Thanks for this - but it gives me a single boolean rather than a list.. :(

Comment: @JamesW -- Sorry, I guess I misunderstood the sentence:  "What I would like to do is identify if 0.0 is present in any of the sublists (true or false)."